# How to configure PostgreSQL Provider in Terraform

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, terraform

This is a bit of a newbie attempt but I am trying to use 'PostgreSQL Provider' to grant permissions in postgres database table access to the google_sql_user via Terraform.

The provider needs to have 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' variable set to service account file.

Is there any other way to store the file and access it in env variable in terraform?

I am not even sure if it is the right way to grant permissions to the users.

Note: The users are not machine or application.

Edit: The question is regarding granting permissions in postgres database from Terraform.

Comment: github repositories have a dedicated place for secrets, read more: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions

Comment: ... and this question is not really about PostgreSQL or Terraform just secrets in github

Comment: There is a much better way: Workload Identity Federation. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enabling-keyless-authentication-from-github-actions

Comment: You are asking more than one question or you are not clear what your problem is. Show what you have tried and define your objective and the problem.